# three.js meshBasicMaterial color not recognized

Tags: javascript, three.js, mesh

Here is my code to render a red coloured mesh (hex:0xff0000) into the scene. But my every try is failed.I only keeping on seeing only a black mesh .
if i change the color to blue or green it works fine.

```
<script>
 this.initScene = function() {
    this.renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
    this.renderer.setClearColor(0xd9dadd);
    document.getElementById('webgl-container').
    appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onDocumentMouseDown, false);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onmousemove, false);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.onDocumentMouseUp, false);
    this.light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,
            (innerWidth) / innerHeight,
            1,
            1000
            );
    this.camera.lookAt(this.scene.position);
    this.camera.position.z = 8;
    this.scene.add(this.camera);
    this.scene.add(this.light);
    this.plane = new THREE.Mesh(
   new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1000, 1000, 8,8), 
   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff, visible: false}));
    this.plane.name = 'plane';
    this.scene.add(this.plane);
    this.render();
   }

this.newActor = function() {
    this.dynamicTexture = new THREEx.DynamicTexture(512, 512);
    this.dynamicTexture.context.font = "bolder 110px Verdana";
//this.dynamicTexture.texture.anisotropy = this.renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
    this.dynamicTexture.clear('cyan');
    this.dynamicTexture.drawText('this.id', undefined, 256, 'black');
    var box = new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.8, 0.8, 0),
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                           color: 0xff0000,
                            map :this.dynamicTexture.texture})
            );
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In three.js, `material.map` is tinted by `material.color`.

In your case, the map has color cyan ( `0x00ffff` ), and you have set the material color to red ( `0xff0000` ).

Cyan has color intensity only in the green and blue channels, but red does not have any color intensity in those channels. Consequently, the final color is black.

In most cases, when assigning a map to a material, you will want to leave the material color as white, the default.

three.js r.80

Comment: thank you , your solution works fine. i assign white color to material .